# Setting enviorment variables in Informix database to start

Tags: informix

i have installed Informix database server(11.70) successfully.but get problems in starting the DB server.when i run it give me error.

```
Warning: could not access INFORMIXSQLHOSTS /opt/IBM/informix1/etc/sqlhosts.
```

How to create this sqlhosts file and what is the exact content of this file.in my etc directory i have some similar files named :

sqlhosts.cmsm.sample

sqlhosts.cmsm.sample.all

sqlhosts.cmsm.sample.client

sqlhosts.cmsm.sample.er

sqlhosts.demo

sqlhosts.ol_informix1170_1

sqlhosts.std

but there is no file named sqlhosts in /etc/ folder.please guideline how to prepare this file ??

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you created the instance during the install process. From your file list I suspect that the name was "ol_informix1170_1". I'd say, but I cannot be 100% sure that in order to setup the environment for your Informix instance, you need (as a minimum) set the following:

```
INFORMIXDIR=/opt/IBM/informix1
INFORMIXSQLHOSTS=/opt/IBM/informix1/etc/sqlhosts.ol_informix1170_1
ONCONFIG=onconfig.ol_informix1170_1  #check if this file exists (in $INFORMIXDIR/etc)
INFORMIXSERVER=ol_informix1170_1     #check that this is the value of the SERVERNAME in the previous file
PATH=$PATH:$INFORMIXDIR/bin

export INFORMIXDIR INFORMIXSERVER ONCONFIG INFORMIXSQLHOSTS PATH
```

Regards